# scroll top java script function?

Tags: html, scroll, href

In html, Generally people use scrolling to top of page like:

```
<a href="#top" title="Scroll back to the top">Back to the top</a>
```

But i need the web page go to top after clicking the link.
file of left.php:

```
<div class"ida0">
   <a href="news.php" target="right_frame"  onclick="scrollToTop()">Link 1</a>
</div>
```

Because my web page is like this.
* main.php
* left.php
* right.php

|----------------------------|
|----------------------------|
||some image || contents|
||---------------- || of link ||
||---------------- || --------||
||---------------- || --------||
||---------------- || --------||
||-----link1------ || --------||
||-----link2------ || --------||
||---------------- || --------||
||---------------- || --------||

I used this But didn't work.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function scrollToTop()
    {
   document.getElementById(ida0).scrollTop = 0; //It scrolls to top
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function scrollToTop() {
    window.scroll(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: when i put the code "window.scroll(0, 0);" in the "left.php" file, and clicked the link, it worked well, went to the top of window. But when i opened main.php, and clicked the link in left.php it didn't worked.

Comment: @trante: Try `window.top.scroll(0, 0);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to jump instantly to the top, you can use [window.scrollTo(0, 0)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.scrollTo), or if you would like to animate the scroll, you can use something like [jQuery.smoothScroll](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll).